# Sector and Geography granularity issue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table Time

[image]

When the user selects period from february 2020 tç february 2021,I expect to get the following result

[image]

But what I get

[image]

How to correct the issue with the granularity?

Here is the pbix file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vf0khr7MbnDTVBzycNgJsaJufwd9F8D_/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: How 52 for xxxx? 208 is the correct sum for xxxx for the given date range.

Comment: It's the result 22+30. The value of time it's almost the same for the combination geo and sector for the same project name and date. The good result it's 52 for the project xxxx. My problem is with granularity

Comment: There are 4 different geo for xxxx. How you wants to distinct them? or keep just one value from 4?

Comment: I want to do sum regardless geo and sector. Like sum distinct value of time For each project name and for each date range.

Comment: Please check the added answer meet your requirement or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below **Measure**-

```
project_wise_time = 
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table (2)',
        'Table (2)'[Project Name],'Table (2)'[DATE],
        "distinct_value", DISTINCT('Table (2)'[Time ])
    ),
    [distinct_value]
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]